# Meteor JS Uncaught ReferenceError: Session is not defined

Tags: javascript, session, meteor

I have a very simple event set up in the \client\main.js file:

```
Template.hello.events({
  'click button': function () {
    Session.set('selectedPlayer', 'session value test');
    Session.get('selectedPlayer');
    var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
    console.log(selectedPlayer);
  }
});
```

However, whenever I click the button, the console says `"Uncaught ReferenceError: Session is not defined"` on the row with the first `Session.set` call.

Other similar questions blame this on the fact that the Session only works on the client and not the server - but as far as I know everything in the folder "client" is automatically client-side.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found the answer.

It seems **session** is no longer part of the default meteor package. You need to run `meteor add session` for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Add **Session** to your application, run this command in your terminal,

```
meteor add session
```

Import statement is used to load them,

```
import { Session } from 'meteor/session'
```